# Error while running basic Hadoop wordcount in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, word-count, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am way too new to Cloudera and Hadoop. I encountered a problem while executing the following command in Cloudera Quickstart VM terminal

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output
```

These are the lines I get on executing the above command

```
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop-mapreduce]$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount /user/cloudera/input /user/cloudera/output
15/10/28 19:24:22 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/10/28 19:24:23 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/cloudera/.staging/job_1446055649734_0002
15/10/28 19:24:24 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/input
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/input
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:264)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:385)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:492)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1324)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

[cloudera@quickstart hadoop-mapreduce]$
```

Comment: what the output of `hdfs dfs -ls /user/cloudera/input` ? Just make sure you do have the input folder.

Answer (score 0):

please access your hadoop 50070 port and check your input path , if it not exist, then execute wordcount will be cause a Exception!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer @Qin Dong Liang . I have checked the port 50070 in my browser and it is opening namenode information of hadoop and the problem still persists.

Comment: my mean is you open 50070 web ui ,and check you input path whther exist,   first open 50070 web ui , second , click Utilities => choose Browse the file system ,third check you input path !